# How to list all names and descriptions of a custom taxonomy

Tags: posts, taxonomy, customization, description

I have a custom taxonomy (toolkit-sections) inside a custom post type (toolkit-tools) and I'm looking to just list the taxonomy names and descriptions from toolkit-sections on a homepage.

I don't want to list any posts from inside these taxonomies, I just want to show what the taxonomies are called and what their descriptions are.

Do you know how to do this? I really, really would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

In your case, something like this ought to get you started:

```
$term_list = get_terms( 'taxonomy_name', 'hide_empty=0&orderby=name' );

foreach( $term_list as $term ) {
    echo "<li>" . $term->name . $term->description . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks Gwendydd - I think when I had been trying to do this myself at midnight last night I was forgetting about the hide-empty! I'm so grateful for your help here.